# detecting persons on video/frames

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am learning neural networks and i have set goal to train NN to detect persons on camera/video.

I understand basic concept of NN. What i am not sure is how should i approach this goal.

If i wanted to train NN to recognize human it would be classification problem - its either human or not, i would put training data set of human and non human object for it to learn.

However, how should i train NN in this type of scenario? What would output layer look like? Would the output be just the coordination of humans or how can i train it to detect all persons on video/camera? How to approach this?

What came to my mind is to output layer be composed of nerusons which activision consist of vector ( x coords , y coords , width, height ). However in this case, i would have to neuron for all combination? Wouldnt that be overkill?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of output format is very similar to what **YOLO** algorithm for **object detection** does, but you didn't mentioned using CNNs. YOLO uses something like your scheme on top of convolutional neural networks.

The idea is to use CNNs to extract features and then apply layer that does what you described per patch, or in other words apply your idea in a sliding window fashion.

You can see this video [(CNN27. Object Detection: Bounding Box Predictions)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFjHkXhkYzA) and next ones (CNN28-31) for more details.